# How to use Django AutoSlug in Custom Form

Tags: python, django

I am working on a project and using the django-autoslug package to auto generate slugs for me. The package does its job perfectly well and I like it. So far, I can edit slugs from the admin panel when I added editable=True which works well from the admin panel. Now I want a working system where users can easily edit there slug from an UpdateForm in the UpdateView. I tried the official docs but I think it is limited to the admin panel and no support for the regular custom forms.

Is there any better solution that can solve this for me? A solution that can auto generate forms, and also allow my users update their slug uniquely. I'll be very grateful if I get a solution on this.

Warm Regards.

slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from='name', unique=True, editable=True)

Comment: Slugs should not be editable https://www.django-antipatterns.com/antipattern/modifying-slugs-and-primary-keys-of-model-objects.html Cool URI's don't change https://www.w3.org/Provider/Style/URI.html

Comment: All good, thanks a lot for your response. I am happy you shared your thoughts and the link. I'll stick with a one time url for my user base.